# Regex for capturing URL path in groups separated by a forward slash

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract in groups values separated by a /.

A couple of examples:

- /abra/1234fd/kadabra/2314 should return abra, 1234fd, kadabra, 2314
- /abra/1234fd/kadabra should return abra, 1234fd, kadabra
- /abra/1234fd should return abra, 1234fd
- etc.

Thanks in advance

Edit: the thing is that I have an arbitrary number of params (alphanumeric values) separated by a / and I'm looking for a way to make it general.

Comment: What language? Maybe there is a simpler solution...

Comment: Or maybe I should just split it by / and be done with it :)

Comment: I think if you spent some time looking at the urllib you'll find what you need... https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.split()` seems to be what you want:

```
assert '/abra/1234fd/kadabra/2314'.strip('/').split('/') == ['abra', '1234fd', 'kadabra', '2314']
assert '/abra/1234fd/kadabra'.strip('/').split('/') == ['abra', '1234fd', 'kadabra']
assert '/abra/1234fd'.strip('/').split('/') == ['abra', '1234fd']
```

If you must have a regular expression, try this:

```
import re
assert re.findall('[^/]+', '/abra/1234fd/kadabra/2314') == ['abra', '1234fd', 'kadabra', '2314']
assert re.findall('[^/]+', '/abra/1234fd/kadabra') == ['abra', '1234fd', 'kadabra']
assert re.findall('[^/]+', '/abra/1234fd') == ['abra', '1234fd']
```